# How to open developer page on Google Play Store (market://)

Tags: android, google-play

Recently, Google Play lets developers create developer page.

Here is the example : https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5700313618786177705

I try to find developer page Uri link (market://...) that I can use but I can't find it on Android Developer page. (http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://..."));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I add the correct solutions to your questions. (market://dev?id=5700313618786177705) doesn't open the playstore app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply call market://dev?id=xxx
e.g.:

```
market://dev?id=5700313618786177705
```

I hope, this suits your needs!

Best,
Jacko

Comment: Thanks, it works! @Rayes, It works when putting this as setData(Uri) in Intent

Comment: @Rayes: This works as follows:
`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://dev?id=5700313618786177705")))`

Comment: This does not work for me. Using complete https url works.

Comment: That doesn't work, it simply crashes. I've downvoted this!!! I don't understand why this answer is accepted. Does the asker tested it in the first place? Using the regular link "https" works

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=7809285959465313029")));
```

Using market URI does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
//Method for intent to Google playstore developer page

 private void M_Intent2developerpage() {
       Intent intentdev = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intentdev.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:Google Inc."));
   //here Developer Name is very case-sensitive . change your developer name as shown in developers page.
       if (!MyStartActivity(intentdev)) {
           intentdev.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5700313618786177705"));
           if (!MyStartActivity(intentdev)) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open Android Google PlayStore, please install the Google play app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }


//Method checks if any problem when Intent

 public boolean MyStartActivity(Intent aIntent) {
        try {
            startActivity(aIntent);
            return true;
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin with the developer name instead of the developer Id:

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
     Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=MyDeveloperName")))
```

Answer (score -1):

To open app on google play: you can use:

```
getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=<developer_id>)));
```

OR

```
getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://dev?id=<developer_id>)));
```